# Delphi - TXMLDocument created at run-time generates AV, with component on the form is working

Tags: delphi, delphi-2006, txmldocument

I'm creating an instance of TXMLDocument at runtime, to load and parse a XML file. You can check the code below:

```
    unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, xmldom, XMLIntf, msxmldom, XMLDoc, StdCtrls;

type
  Txml = class(TForm)
//    XMLDocument1: TXMLDocument;
    Memo1: TMemo;
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  xml: Txml;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure Txml.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var    i,j:integer;
       aNode:IXMLNode;
       ws:String;
       XMLDocument1:TXMLDocument;
begin
 Memo1.Lines.Clear;
 XMLDocument1 := TXMLDocument.Create(nil);
 try
  XMLDocument1.LoadFromFile('C:\a.xml');
  XMLDocument1.Active := true;
  aNode := XMLDocument1.ChildNodes.First;
  while aNode<>nil do
  begin
   for i := 0 to aNode.ChildNodes.Count-1 do
    begin
     if aNode.ChildNodes[i].NodeName = 'Role' then
      begin
       Memo1.Lines.Add('Tag - '+aNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes['Tag'].Text);
       for j := 0 to aNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes.Count-1 do
        if aNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[j].HasChildNodes then
         begin
          ws :=  VarToStr(aNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[j].ChildValues['Tag']);
          if trim(ws)<>'' then
           Memo1.Lines.Add(ws);
          ws :=  VarToStr(aNode.ChildNodes[i].ChildNodes[j].ChildValues['Value']);
          if trim(ws)<>'' then
           Memo1.Lines.Add(ws);
         end;
      end;
    end;
   aNode := aNode.NextSibling;
  end;
  XMLDocument1.Active := false;
 finally
   FreeAndNil(XMLDocument1);
 end;
end;

end.
```

The problem is that this is generating an AV. As you probably have seen, before the component was on the form (//    XMLDocument1: TXMLDocument;).

Why when the component was on the form the code was working, but when I'm creating it at run-time it generates AV?

LE:
**solution**: based on the answers/comments and Delphi Help:

```
XMLDocument1 : IXMLDocument;  //not TXMLDocument

XMLDocument1 := LoadXMLDocument(...);

FreeAndNil;// must be deleted
```

Comment: Use [IXMLDocument](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/XMLIntf.IXMLDocument) and as constructor [NewXMLDocument](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/XMLDoc.NewXMLDocument).

Comment: Where exactly does AV happens?

Comment: You should do `ANode := nil;` after the loop to release the node instance before closing and freeing `XMLDocument1`.

Comment: And about instantiating of the [IXMLDocument](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/XMLIntf.IXMLDocument), I've overlooked that you're loading a file, so [LoadXMLDocument](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/XMLDoc.LoadXMLDocument) is the right function for you.

Comment: @TLama - didn't saw your comment, I was editing the question with the solution. +1

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From what I know you should be using interface `IDoc: IXMLDocument;` instead.

From docs:

> When TXMLDocument is created without an Owner, it behaves like an
>   interfaced object. That is, when all references to its interface are
>   released, the TXMLDocument instance is automatically freed. When
>   TXMLDocument is created with an Owner, however, it behaves like any
>   other component, and is freed by its Owner.

In other words, when creating a `TXMLDocument` instance with a `nil` Owner, *do not* call `Free()` or `FreeAndNil()` on the instance, and you **must** assign the object to an `IXMLDocument` variable so its now-active reference count is managed properly.

Comment: In other words, when creating a `TXMLDocument` instance with a `nil` Owner, *do not* call `Free()` or `FreeAndNil()` on the instance, and you *must* assign the object to an `IXMLDocument` variable so its now-active reference count is managed properly.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide an `Owner` to `TXMLDocument` when creating it in run-time.

```
XMLDocument1 := TXMLDocument.Create(xml);
```

Comment: yes, indeed, this soleve the problem, but all this code will be placed into a special class, inside an unit :) +1